# Is there any guarantee that all of threads in WaveFront (OpenCL) always synchronized?

Tags: concurrency, opencl, simd, gpgpu, amd-gpu

As known, there are WARP (in CUDA) and WaveFront (in OpenCL): http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse471/13sp/lectures/GPUsStudents.pdf

[image]

- **WARP** in CUDA: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture

> 4.1. SIMT Architecture
>
> ...
>
> A **warp executes one common instruction at a time**, so full efficiency
>   is realized when all 32 threads of a warp agree on their execution
>   path. If threads of a warp diverge via a data-dependent conditional
>   branch, the warp serially executes each branch path taken, disabling
>   threads that are not on that path, and when all paths complete, the
>   threads converge back to the same execution path. Branch divergence
>   occurs only within a warp; **different warps execute independently**
>   regardless of whether they are executing common or disjoint code
>   paths.
>
> The SIMT architecture is akin to SIMD (Single Instruction, Multiple
>   Data) vector organizations in that a single instruction controls
>   multiple processing elements. A key difference is that SIMD vector
>   organizations expose the SIMD width to the software, whereas SIMT
>   instructions specify the execution and branching behavior of a single
>   thread.

- **WaveFront** in OpenCL: https://sites.google.com/site/csc8820/opencl-basics/opencl-terms-explained#TOC-Wavefront

> During runtime, the first wavefront is sent to the compute unit to
>   run, then the second wavefront is sent to the compute unit, and so on.
>   Work **items within one wavefront are executed in parallel** and in **lock
>   steps**. But **different wavefronts are executed sequentially**.

---

I.e. we know, that:

- threads in **WARP** (CUDA) - are SIMT-threads, which **always executes the same instructions at each time and always are stay synchronized** - i.e. threads of WARP are the same as [lanes of SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_threads) (on CPU)
- threads in **WaveFront** (OpenCL) - are threads, which always executes in parallel, but not necessarily all the threads perform the exact same instruction, and not necessarily all of the threads are synchronized

But is there any guarantee that all of the threads in the WaveFront always synchronized such as threads in WARP or as lanes in SIMD?

---

**Conclusion**:

1. **WaveFront-threads (items) are always synchronized - lock step**: *"wavefront executes a number of work-items in lock step relative to each other."*
2. **WaveFront mapped on SIMD-block**: *"all work-items in the wavefront go to both paths of flow control"*
3. I.e. **each WaveFront-thread (item) mapped to SIMD-lanes**

page-20: http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/07/AMD_Accelerated_Parallel_Processing_OpenCL_Programming_Guide-rev-2.7.pdf

> Chapter 1 OpenCL Architecture and AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
>
> 1.1 Terminology
>
> ...
>
> Wavefronts and work-groups are two concepts relating to compute
>   kernels that provide data-parallel granularity. A **wavefront**
>   executes a number of work-items in **lock step** relative to each
>   other. **Sixteen workitems are execute in parallel across the vector
>   unit**, and the whole wavefront is covered over four clock cycles. It
>   is the lowest level that flow control can affect. This means that if
>   two work-items inside of a wavefront go divergent paths of flow
>   control, **all work-items in the wavefront go to both paths of flow
>   control**.

This is true for: http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_OpenCL_Programming_Optimization_Guide2.pdf

- **(page-45)** Chapter 2 OpenCL Performance and Optimization for **GCN Devices**
- **(page-81)** Chapter 3 OpenCL Performance and Optimization for **Evergreen and Northern Islands Devices**

Comment: also amd's HD5000 and HD4000 series have SIMD width 4 but wavefront size is 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can query some values:

```
CL_DEVICE_WAVEFRONT_WIDTH_AMD
CL_DEVICE_SIMD_WIDTH_AMD
CL_DEVICE_WARP_SIZE_NV
CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE
```

but only from host side as I know.

Lets assume these queries returned `64` and your question gives importance to threads' implicit synchronization.

What if someone chooses local range = 4?

Since opencl abstracts hardware clockwork from developer, you can't know what actual SIMD or WAVEFRONT size is from within kernel execution in runtime.

For example, AMD NCU has 64 shaders but it has 16-wide SIMD, 8-wide SIMD, 4-wide SIMD, 2-wide SIMD and even two scalar units inside same compute unit.

4 local threads could be shared on two scalars and one 2-wide unit or any other combination of SIMDs. Kernel code can't know this. Even if it knows somehow computing things, **you can't know which SIMD combination will be used for next kernel execution(or even next workgroup) at runtime in a random compute-unit(64 shaders).**

Or a GCN CU, which has 4x16 SIMDs in it, could allocate 1 thread per SIMD, making all 4 threads totally independent. If they all reside in same SIMD, youre lucky. There is no guarantee knowing that "before" kernel execution. Even after you know, next kernel could be different since there is no guarantee of choosing same SIMD allocation(background kernels, 3d visualization softwares, even OS could be putting bubbles in pipelines)

**There is no guarantee of commanding/hinting/querying of N threads to run as same SIMD or same WARP before kernel execution**. Then in the kernel, there is no command to get a thread's wavefront index just like get_global_id(0). Then after kernel, you can't rely on array results since next kernel execution may not use same SIMDs for exact same items. Even some items from other wavefronts could be swapped with an item from current wavefront just for an optimization by driver or hardware (nvidia has loadbalancer lately and could have been doing this, also NCU of amd may use similar thing in future)

Even if you guess right combination of threads on SIMDs on your hardware and driver, it could be totally different in another computer.

---

**If its for a performance point of view, you could try:**

- zero-branch in kernel code
- zero kernels running in background
- gpu is not being used for monitor output
- gpu is not being used for some visualization software

**Just to make sure %99 probability**, there are no bubbles in pipelines so all threads retire an instruction at the same cycle(or at least synchronize at latest retiring one).

Or, add a fence after every instruction to synchronize on global or local memory which is very slow. Fences make workitem level synhronization, barriers make local group level synchronization. There are no wavefront synchronization commands.

Then, those threads that run within same SIMD will behave synchronized. But you may not know which threads those are and which SIMDs.

For the 4-thread example, using float16 for all calculations may let the driver use 16-wide SIMDs of AMD GCN CU to compute but then they are not threads anymore, only variables. But this should have better synchronization on data, than threads.

There are more complex situations such as:

- 4 threads in same SIMD but one thread calculation generates some NaN value and does an extra normalization(taking 1-2 cycle maybe) on that. 3 others should wait for completion but it works independently of data related slowdowns.
- 4 threads in same wavefront are in a loop and one of them stuck forever. 3 of them wait for the 4th one to finish forever or driver detects and moves it to another free-empty SIMD? Or 4th one waits for other 3 at the same time because they are not moving too!
- 4 threads doing atomic operations, one by one.
- Amd's HD5000 series gpu has SIMD width 4(or 5) but wavefront size is 64.

Comment: Thank you! Does it mean, that WaveFront doesn't guarantees that all threads of WaveFront execute one common instruction at a time, because half of WaveFront can be executed on one SIMD-unit and other half on another SIMD-unit, or halfs of WaveFront can be executed sequentially on one SIMD-unit small-width. But does WaveFront guarantees lockstep, that **the first half can not fall behind the second half more than 1 instructions**, so my code can not tell the difference, threads of WaveFront are executed in parallel or not. https://hsto.org/files/824/593/10e/82459310e0d74b91b8715005b8f04352.jpg

Comment: There is "must not fall behind more than 1 instructions" but it must be under non-divergent code. Nvidia may be doing it "compute both sides" while amd may be doing it "compute both sides one after another" with holes in it.

Comment: And nobody writes about if nvidia is computing the "else" part of an "if" secretly on another SIMD.

Comment: Old architectures use VLIW not SIMD. And on GCN's one thread views one SIMD element. float16 is just 16 floats, that is 16 elements in 16 registers not one full register. And there seems to be no reason to spread 4 threads to different stream processors.

Answer (score 1):

Wavefronts guarantee lockstep. That's why on older compilers you can omit the synchronizations if your local group contains only one wavefront. (You can no longer do this on newer compilers, who will interprete the dependency wrong and give you wrong code. But on the other hand newer compilers will omit the synchronizations for you if your local group contains only one wavefront.)

One stream processer is like one core of CPU. It will repeatly run one 16-wide vector instruction four times to fulfill the 64 so called "threads" in a wavefront. Actually one wavefront is more a thread than what we call a thread on a GPU.

Comment: just tested llvm output of some float4 kernel, it has 4x number of operations for each vector item. so you are right about only 1 SIMD element per thread. But using vector makes it easier to compiler to use vector alu instead of scalar alu, or make it better distribute workitems.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik There is no build in vector operation in GCN for a "thread". When a variable's value is consistent across a wavefront, the compiler will choose scalar alu to save vecter register, otherwise vector alu is always used. GCN is very different from pervious architecture. Using vector types sometimes helps the compiler to use vector load/store, but for the most of time the compiler can do it right even without using vector types.

Comment: Thank you! Can you clarify the difference between **1.** "older compilers you can omit the synchronizations if your local group contains only one wavefront" and **2.** "newer compilers will omit the synchronizations for you if your local group contains only one wavefront". In both cases I use only one wavefront and synchronizations are omited, but what is the difference?

Comment: @Alex it could be using 16 threads per compute unit and not using other 48 threads(or having idle stages between those 3 SIMDS)

Comment: @Alex For newer drivers, from 16.x I guess, you **can't omit synchronizations in your code**, or the compiled result **could be wrong**  (Compiler bug I guess). But the compiler will remove them for you in the final result. For older drivers, you **have to remove synchronizations by yourself**, since the compiler will not remove them and **there will be unnecessary overhead in runtime**.

Comment: @Alex It is possible that on even older drivers(before I touched OpenCL), the compiler will remove unnecessary synchronizations(that not doing so is, again, a bug), because I think I've heard of it...