# Should we use the vector-types, if we want to write once optimized code for both: CPU and GPU?

Tags: vectorization, opencl, gpgpu, amd-processor, amd-gpu

As known, OpenCL vector-type `float16`

- `float16` on AMD **GPU** (GCN) doesn't use addition vector operations, because vector operations used even without vector-types by using WaveFront (each thread = each SIMD-lane). I.e. `float16` can help only for load/store on large width bus of memory, for example on HBM (High Bandwidth Memory): https://stackoverflow.com/a/42315728/1558037
- but `float16` on AMD **CPU** is recommended to use for involving SIMD-lanes of CPU (because each thread = each whole CPU-Core, not SIMD-lane): http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/opencl-resources/programming-in-opencl/image-convolution-using-opencl/image-convolution-using-opencl-a-step-by-step-tutorial-5/

[image]

---

As a result:

- on **GCNs** one thread views one SIMD element - i.e. one **thread mapped on one SIMD-lane**): [Is there any guarantee that all of threads in WaveFront (OpenCL) always synchronized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259118/is-there-any-guarantee-that-all-of-threads-in-wavefront-opencl-always-synchron#comment71785189_42260706)
- on **CPU** one **thread mapped on whole one CPU-Core** (with many SIMD-blocks each with many SIMD-lanes)

I.e. vector-types such as `float16` does not matter much for the GPU, but are of great importance for the CPU.

Should we use the vector-types, if we want to write once optimized OpenCL-code for both architectures: CPU and GPU?

---

**Conclusion:**

Vector types are not much needed for GPU or Intel-CPU, but needed for AMD-CPU.

Comment: Did you check how many VGPRs are used when using float16 vs float, using an ISA code output from a profiler like CodeXL ?

Comment: @huseyin tugrul buyukisik   No, I didn't. What do you mean, are there some mistakes in my statements?

Comment: no just telling some optimizations are seen that way. For example my gpu compiles to use vgpr even When i dont use vectors. Vgpr have more memory than sgpr in my amd gpu

Comment: Its more like readability on "scalar" architectures (even if they work on SIMDs)

Comment: @huseyin tugrul buyukisik  Do you mean that using `float4` instead of `float` can be optimized by compiler for super-scalar & pipeline architectures, such as 4 independent `float`-operations, which can be executed in parallel on different ALUs? Look like as there for Reduce: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27748348/1558037

Comment: as far as I know, GPUs have deep pipelines too,  so there shouldn't be a reason not to complete 1 float while issuing other 3. Also I've read somewhere that GCN was capable of completing 1 vector element fp in 4 cycles(so must be like 7-8 for 4 elements) on top of 1 scalar element fp in same 4 cycles using instruction level parallelism

Comment: Normal vector instructions(which uses vector registers, not instructions for vector type) complete in 4 cycles, but each instruction only process data from 16 threads. The same vector instruction in code will execute 4 times to fill the wavefront and the latency is automatically hidden, and is completely hidder if next instruction is a vector instruction again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if performance is what you're concerned about, it is almost always a bad idea to use a same kernel for different architectures. Pre-GCN's want vectors, GCN's want scalars, CPU's can handle both with Intel driver but only if you are awared of it, and I don't know how AMD's driver is doing on a CPU. While CPU need wider vectors than GPU. CPU's rely on cache and GPU's rely more on scratch memory. GPU's have insanely more registers than CPU's can even dream of...

On GCN's actually vector types just make me feel my code looks nicer, and save some time on typing and making mistakes. `float v[4]`, `float4 v`, or even `float v0, v1, v2, v3`, doesn't make much difference for the most of time.

And as said before, Intel's CL driver can map a thread to a SIMD element, which make one core 8 CL threads.

Comment: amd using SSE when using vectors I tested it but its nowhere close to handtuned assembly performance(maybe its just my fx8150). intels compiler is much better. going from float to float4 makes it x2 - x2.5 as fast and float8 makes close to x3  as fast.

Comment: maybe performance gap between assembly comes from AVX-SSE - MMX transitions if there exists

Comment: On intel driver, float can be as fast as float8 if you've done it right. But using AVX without CL is a lot easier and more reasonable, at least I think.